# Concordanza del discorso indiretto

Tags: grammar, verbs

La seguente frase mi è stata rivolta da una persona mentre mi descriveva un evento accadutole poche ore prima:"*...allora io ho pensato che quando questi qua se ne sarebbero andati, andavo a fare gli auguri*" (io al posto di `andavo` avrei detto `sarei andato`). Comunque, va bene il `sarebbero` o ci vuole il `fossero`?

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!!

Comment: @abarisone Grazie!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tratta di un [discorso indiretto](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discorso_indiretto), quindi per capire che tempi usare la prima cosa da considerare è la frase effettivamente pensata / pronunciata, che in questo caso penso sia

> Quando questi qua se ne andranno, andrò a fare gli auguri.

in particolare con i verbi al futuro.

Secondo le regole di [concordanza grammaticale del discorso indiretto](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discorso_indiretto#Discorso_indiretto_e_concordanza_grammaticale_dei_tempi), i futuri diventano condizionali passati.

> Ho pensato che quando questi qua se ne **sarebbero andati**, **sarei andato** a fare gli auguri.

Le altre versioni mi paiono sbagliate. L'istinto di usare l'imperfetto o il congiuntivo probabilmente è dovuto alla somiglianza con altri tipi di [periodo ipotetico](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodo_ipotetico)

> Se se ne andassero, andrei a fare gli auguri.
>
> Se se ne fossero andati, sarei andato a fare gli auguri.
>
> Se se ne andavano, andavo a fargli gli auguri. (*L'indicativo imperfetto qui è un registro informale, incorretto secondo la grammatica "tradizionale" ma usato in pratica, soprattutto nel parlato*)

che però secondo me qui non sono quello che il parlante ha in mente.

Non mi suona 100% sbagliata, anche se molto di basso registro e da usarsi solo nel parlato, la versione con i due indicativi imperfetti, modellata sul periodo ipotetico

> Ho pensato che quando questi qua se ne **andavano**, **andavo** a fare gli auguri.

Non la insegnerei in un corso di lingua, ma non mi sembra neppure impossibile sentirla per strada. Direi che l'indicativo imperfetto ha una tendenza a sostituirsi in generale a tutti i congiuntivi e condizionali passati, nel parlato molto informale. E in questo caso effettivamente anche l'uso di "questi qua" e la ripetizione del verbo "andare" suggeriscono un registro informale. Mischiare le due versioni, però, è una cosa che mi stride.

Comment: “L'indicativo imperfetto qui tecnicamente è incorretto”. Non è corretto dire che non è corretto. :) È un registro diverso da quello più formale a cui appartengono l'uso del congiuntivo e del condizionale, ma è pienamente parte della lingua italiana e lo si trova usato anche in grandi autori. Cf. anche Serianni, XIV.151.

Comment: @DaG Grazie del commento, ho corretto quell'affermazione (e aggiunto che, analogamente, non è impensabile neppure sentire qui la versione con due indicativi imperfetti).

Comment: Scusa ma la frase da cui partire non dovrebbe essere `Quando questi qua se ne saranno andati, io andrò...`? Il saranno andati mi dà l'idea che questi qua hanno finito di andarsene e solo quando non ci sono più io andrò... Quando se ne andranno invece lascia aperta la possibilità che io andrò mentre loro se ne stanno andando...

Comment: @Hastur Sì, concordo con te, la tua versione funziona meglio. Quando si passa al discorso indiretto, comunque, questa sfumatura di significato si perde.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Да нет, наверное. (Si' no, probabilmente `:-)`). Per rendere la finitezza dell'azione passata (di questi qua) potresti usare il congiuntivo trapassato, come hai riportato anche tu pur non ritienendolo essere l'intenzione del parlante: (Solo)_quando ne fossero andati, sarei andato a fare gli auguri_...

Answer (score 0):

Nella prima frase ci va il `fossero`, mentre nella seconda il `sarei andato`, perché la prima frase indica la condizione (se/che) e regge il congiuntivo, mentre la seconda la conseguenza, quindi regge il condizionale.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Comment: Sono d'accordo che *fossero* sia un'alternativa (alquanto manzoniana, direi), ma così com'è la risposta è carente.